# How to get JPG (RGB Color) from Bin file in Python

Tags: python, rgb, binaryfiles, converters, bin

I am working on biological data which is basically a collection of slices in a 3-dimensional array. I can get all the slices in **.bin files** but I am looking for some tool in python that will help me to retrieve **RGB image files**. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (PIL fork).
If you can convert your binary files to a numpy array, you can also convert it to an image with [PIL.Image.fromarray](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=fromarray#PIL.Image.fromarray).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But I could not convert the binary files to numpy array. I also tried "im = Image.fromarray(a)". It seems to be working if I read an image file, store it in numpy array and then try to convert. But my original file is HDF5 file from where I can get the data in binary (.bin) files. If I try to get my image files directly from array it is generating the grayscale image. But my goal is to get the RGB image. That is why I am trying to get RGB image files from the binary files.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how to convert binary file to numpy array?